# Call method in View from ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

I am starting to learn Xamarin, so I am a noob.

I am trying to show a SnackBar or Toast using the `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Extensions` NuGet Package.

I can't seem to find a way to show a Toast or Snackbar in the ViewModel. The only way I found to display it was in the `View.xaml.cs`.

I created a method `ShowToast()` in my `View.xaml.cs`. I would like to know how do I call the `ShowToast()` method in my `ViewModel.cs`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your View model you can call

Not only for showing the snackbar,but also to handle navigation

`await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplaySnackbarAsync(message, actionButtonText, action, duration);`